# image from memory stream

Tags: image, memorystream

i use a daylipilot month and i would like ta have a jpeg but i have a memorystream

and i have the error

A generic error occurred in GDI+. when i save it

```
Dim test As Bitmap
            Dim e1 As Image
            Dim image As MemoryStream
            image = DayPilotMonth.Export(ImageFormat.Jpeg)
            e1 = System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromStream(image)
            e1.Save("/APP/temp/test.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg)
```

how to do for save the image from a memory stream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim e1 As Image
    Dim image As MemoryStream
    image = dpmStructures.Export(ImageFormat.Jpeg)
    e1 = System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromStream(image)
    e1.Save(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp & "\calgeneral.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg)
```